# ADF Copy Activity insert XML column to Azure SQL DB fails

Tags: xml, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have some files in Azure blob that contains 10 columns (9 are strings, 1 is XML). The destination table also has 9 strings and 1 xml datatype

I'm receiving the below error when inserting the data. If I remove the XML column then no problem to insert.

Any idea to about this? The XML is well formed because I have no issue inserting to SQL Server on prem

Maybe XML is not supported as I dont see XML data type available in the source or sink data type options...?

Activity Copy Data1 failed: ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'XML parsing: line 1, character 55, unable to switch the encoding',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=XML parsing: line 1, character 55, unable to switch the encoding,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=9402,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=9402,State=1,Message=XML parsing: line 1, character 55, unable to switch the encoding,},],'

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** XML file type in copy activity is not supported.

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

[XML file type in copy activity. along with XML schema validation](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/17508058-xml-file-type-in-copy-activity-along-with-xml-sc)

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Comment: Voted! Anyway it wasnt an XML file type. It was an XML column in a JSON file type. The Work around I found was to import the XML column as a string (varchar(max)) and then once in SQL DB convert to XML

Comment: XML is finally coming to ADF. The status was changed today https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/17508058-xml-file-type-in-copy-activity-along-with-xml-sc